# 3DR Solo Drone WiFi Communication

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, busybox

I have two 3DR Solo UAVs. They have ARM computers in both the drone and the controller running busybox Linux.

From what I understand:
By default the controller acts as a wireless access point. It has the SSID:SoloLink. This picture shows the default setup:
[image: Solo Default Setup]

The controller is the thing with two antennas and it says "SOLO" on the screen and the actual UAV/drone is the X shaped thing.

This works fine and I can directly ssh into the controller (`ssh root@10.1.1.1`) and into the actual solo with (`ssh root@10.1.1.10`)

I can run a command from a python utility at 3DR's github page: `github.com/3drobotics/solo-cli/blob/master/soloutils/wifi.py` (sorry I can only have 2 links because of my reputation) to tell the controller to connect to another WiFi network. I setup a Ubiquity PicoStation to act as a router and to have the SSID:ubnt. 
To connect the controller to the `ubnt` network I connect to the `SoloLink` network and run `solo wifi --name=ubnt`. What this basically does is create a bash script and runs it:

```
if [ "$#" -lt "2" ]; then
    echo "Usage:   `basename $0` timeout_in_seconds command" >&2
    echo "Example: `basename $0` 2 sleep 3 || echo timeout" >&2
    exit 1
fi
cleanup()
{{
    trap - ALRM               #reset handler to default
    kill -ALRM $a 2>/dev/null #stop timer subshell if running
    kill $! 2>/dev/null &&    #kill last job
      exit 124                #exit with 124 if it was running
}}
watchit()
{{
    trap "cleanup" ALRM
    sleep $1& wait
    kill -ALRM $$
}}
watchit $1& a=$!         #start the timeout
shift                    #first param was timeout for sleep
trap "cleanup" ALRM INT  #cleanup after timeout
"$@"& wait $!; RET=$?    #start the job wait for it and save its return value
kill -ALRM $a            #send ALRM signal to watchit
wait $a                  #wait for watchit to finish cleanup
exit $RET                #return the value
SCRIPT
cat > /tmp/setupwifi.sh << 'SCRIPT'
# Delete old files
rm /mnt/rootfs.rw/lib/modules/3.10.17-rt12-*/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko || true
/etc/init.d/hostapd stop
killall wpa_supplicant || true
killall udhcpc || true
cat <<EOF > /etc/wpa_client.conf
network={{
{credentials}
}}
EOF
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sed -i.bak 's/dhcp-option=3.*/dhcp-option=3,10.1.1.1/g' /etc/dnsmasq.conf
sed -i.bak 's/dhcp-option=6.*/dhcp-option=6,8.8.8.8/g' /etc/dnsmasq.conf
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
sleep 2
echo 'connecting to the internet...'
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_client.conf -B
/tmp/timeout.sh 15 udhcpc -i wlan0 || {{
    echo -e "\\nerror: wrong credentials or couldn't connect to wifi network!\\n"
    ifconfig wlan0 down
}}
/etc/init.d/hostapd start
sleep 3
wget -O- http://example.com/ --timeout=5 >/dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? -ne '0' ]]; then
    echo ''
    echo 'error: could not connect to the Internet!'
    echo 'please check your wifi credentials and try again.'
else
    echo 'setting up IP forwarding...'
    insmod /lib/modules/3.10.17-rt12-*/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko 2>/dev/null
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
    iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan0-ap -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0-ap -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
    echo ''
    echo 'success: Solo is now connected to the Internet.'
    echo 'if your computer does not yet have Internet access, try'
    echo "disconnecting and reconnecting to Solo's wifi network."
fi
SCRIPT
chmod +x /tmp/timeout.sh
chmod +x /tmp/setupwifi.sh
bash /tmp/setupwifi.sh > /log/setupwifi.log 2>&1
```

(the {credentials} part is because this script is in a big string in a python script and it substitutes that part with the credentials I pass it)

It seems to enable forwarding, reconfigure dnsmasq, configure wpa_supplicant to connect to my new WiFi network, start wpa_supplicant, and then reconfigure iptables to forward traffic from `wlan0` to `wlan0-ap` interfaces and visa versa. The last `if/else` statement there I modified so that it doesn't do the wget and just runs the `else` block.

This runs fine and I can access the controller from the `ubnt` network. My setup now looks like: 
[image: Solo Setup With Router]
I can ssh to the controller with `ssh root@192.168.1.6` just fine but I don't see the Solo on the network. I tried `nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24` from the laptop and I only see the router (`192.168.1.1`), controller (`192.168.1.6`), and myself (`192.168.1.76`).

**This is were I am stuck**

I want to be able to access the Solo drone from the computer. I get that there are two interfaces on the controller but I do not understand how to bridge them.

The purpose of this is so that I can connect another pair to the same `ubnt` network and then I can monitor/control two UAV's from one central source and a pilot can be in the loop to take control if need be.

Any help or google terms would be appreciated. I don't have much experience with networking and I have been down many rabbit holes searching the commands and terms associated with networking.

Comment: Did you ever make more progress with this? I'm running into a similar problem - I want to run more than one Solo on the same Wi-Fi network, and having this question answered would be good leap in that direction

Comment: @automaton I actually left the place where we were trying to do this and I believe they ended up using a different approach, so I never figured it out. Ned Hodgson looks like he has an idea how to approach it though

Answer (score 2):

I was actually linked to this article by a buddy who wanted my input - I'll share it here as well.

The issue here is missing routes.  In order for your `192.168.1.76` IP (or any `192.168.1.x` IP) to get to `10.1.1.x`, it needs to know the way.  IPs on the same subnet (eg [`10.1.1.1` and `10.1.1.10`] or [`192.168.1.76` and `192.168.1.1`]) do not need a route to communicate; they use a broadcast to find the device with a given IP and send their traffic directly.

In order to go from one subnet to another subnet, you have to define a route.  Additionally, you have to define a route BACK.  So, you can try this (if your router and the solo controller support it):

You need a route in your `192.168.1.1` AP.  The source would be any, the destination would be `10.1.1.0/24`, and the next hop would be `192.168.1.6` - the Solo controller.  The controller is aware of both networks, so if you send traffic destined to `10.1.1.10`, the Solo *should* already know how to get there, and *should* send it along.  Further, because the controller itself is, effectively, the network gateway for the drone (`10.1.1.1`), and it is **also** aware of the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet, that no route would be required there - the route back is implied.

Add that route to your router (`any>10.1.1.0/24>192.168.1.6`) and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input @ned-hodgson! I don't have access to the Solo's anymore, so if someone could confirm this to work on some level, I'll mark it accepted. Ned do you have a short example of using route, or ip route for any one else interested?

Comment: Well in the example above, the required route would need to go on the 'DHCP Enabled' router.  It is likely to have some kind of proprietary GUI.

In most linux distros, it's something like this, assuming the IPs above: 
route add -net 10.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.6

The would not a persistent - it would disappear upon reboot.  Google is your pal for making it either persistent, or re-adding it on reboot (imo easier).

Comment: ahh when I was working on this project, I was thinking I had to set up the routing rules on the controller. Oh well I'll keep this for future reference then!